# Delete a part of a code with ruby with a variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delete-row

I have this code

```
  def index
    require 'net/http'
    require 'json'

    @url = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?start=1&limit=100&CMC_PRO_API_KEY=mykey'
    @uri = URI(@url)
    @response = Net::HTTP.get(@uri)
    @coins = JSON.parse(@response)
    @my_coins = ["BTC", "XRP", "ADA", "ETH", "USDT"]
  end
```

The url brings

```
{"status"=>{"timestamp"=>"2021-02-16T03:55:40.727Z", "error_code"=>0, "error_message"=>nil, "elapsed"=>21, "credit_count"=>1, "notice"=>nil, "total_count"=>4078}, "data"=>[{"id"=>1, "name"=>"
```

Using that variable (@coins) how could I give the instruction to delete everythin until ' "data"=>'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```rb
  def index
    require 'net/http'
    require 'json'

    @url = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?start=1&limit=100&CMC_PRO_API_KEY=mykey'
    @uri = URI(@url)
    @response = Net::HTTP.get(@uri)
    @coins = get_coins(@response)
    @my_coins = ["BTC", "XRP", "ADA", "ETH", "USDT"]
  end

  def get_coins(response)
    coins = JSON.parse(response)
    coins.slice('data')
  end
```

it will give you only 'data' part. because 'data' is a key of hash same as 'status'

the @coins variable will remain the same, but the output is a new variable which is result from slice operation

you can also delete using delete operation then @coins will change to remaining key

```rb
@coins.delete('status')
puts @coins #{"data"=>[{"id"=>1, "name"=>"somename"}]
```

```rb
  def index
    require 'net/http'
    require 'json'

    @url = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?start=1&limit=100&CMC_PRO_API_KEY=mykey'
    @uri = URI(@url)
    @response = Net::HTTP.get(@uri)
    @coins = JSON.parse(response)
    @coins.delete('status')
    @my_coins = ["BTC", "XRP", "ADA", "ETH", "USDT"]
  end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! but in the first part of the anwer, what would happend if it is dynamic, so the hours and days will be changing

Comment: as long as the 'data' key is exist, the result will same, specially if slice is used

Comment: But these lines should be in the controller or inte html? So sorry, I am fighting a little with this stuff

Comment: in your index method if it is suit your purpose. in controller it is fine. if in the html dont forget the ruby tag. my solution is only provide your purpose which is to delete other key and keep the data on your @coins variable. other than that you must define the right way to use the solution based on your condition. i will update my code

Comment: i have updated my code @EduardoRodrigoSilvaOrozco

Comment: That was great, I got it perfectly, one last doubt, if you could tell me.... now my hash is only with 'data' info, how could I convert this to an a, because I am trying to make a loop in the html. and when I apply a variable == x["symbol"] %> it sent me "no implicit conversion of String into Integer" ... is there some way to transform to a hash the 'data' array, allowing me use characters instead of numbers? Thank you so much for your help @dedypuji

Comment: the 'data' is already in hash. if you use data['id'] it will output the value 1 of key 'id'. you can iterate using each {|key, value|} too. i do not know what caused that error, i need more context

Comment: The controller is the one you helped me and this is my html that thows the error in the x["id"], trying to bring the name with the key:
`
<% for x in @coins %>
 <% for coin in @my_coins %>
  <% if coin == x["id"] %>
   <%= x["name"]%>
  <%end%>
 <%end%>
<%end%>

Comment: i think you have to fetch first. the output of @coins is hash with only key is 'data'. before you iterate you have to fetch the key by using @coins.fetch('data'). then it will give you the array of hash.

Comment: Thank you so much, really appreciate your help, works perfectly. Hope I could help you some day. Have a great day. Regards